# Can "pro rata" be used as a verb? And what should the past tense be?

Tags: verbs, latin, simple-past

We are offering prices on some subscriptions which are normally priced for a full year, but allow users to buy only a few months worth.

We're calling these *pro rata prices* and talking about the prices being *pro rataed* or *pro rated* (depending on how we want to pronounce it) — is this good English? What would be a better way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Can pro rata be used as a verb? And what should the past tense be?

The verb form would be *prorate* or *pro rate*. The past tense is *prorated*.

> We're calling these pro rata prices
>   and talking about the prices being pro
>   rataed - is this good english? What
>   would be a better way?

Yes, except you would refer to the prices as *pro-rated*. The second *a* gets dropped.

Answer (score 3):

If you must, I would prefer *pro rated* or *pro-rated* rather than *pro rataed*, which looks as if it has fallen down a hole between Latin and English and is still showing its scars.

Answer (score -4):

The phrase 'Pro Rata' derives from Latin. Therefore you cannot tamper with either form or spelling (For example: 'ad hoc'; 'modus operandi').

You cannot just use it as a verb, and the word 'prorated' is definitely wrong.

Comment: The OED disagrees with you (though it does say 'chiefly U.S.').

Comment: This is a tad too strong. I could just as confidently say that every word in English can be used as a verb. And every single word in this answer derives from another language (including Latin), yet you don't seem to have qualms tampering with their form and spelling.

Comment: The OED has all sorts of examples of  *ad hoc* having been "tampered with": *ad hocness; ad hocing, ad hoc'ing, ad hoc-ing, ad hoccing, ad hocking; ad hoced, ad hoc'ed, ad
hoc'd, ad hoc-ed, ad hocced, ad hocked;  ad hoccism, ad hoc-ism, ad-hoc-ism, adhoc-ism, ad hocism, ad-hocism, adhocism, ad hockism, ad-hockism, adhockism; ad-hoc-ery, ad hoccery, ad- hoccery, adhoccery, ad hoc-ery, adhoc-ery, ad hocery, ad-hocery, adhocery, ad hockery, ad-hockery, adhockery; ad hocracy, ad-hocracy, adhocracy*. The oldest from 1899.

Comment: This answer can be improved by citing a reputable reference which upholds your claim. As it stands, your answer could be taken as a pure statement of opinion and is liable to be downvoted or deleted.